# how to add item into existing json file through php script

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

how to write new data to the .json file using AJAX to update the .json file with additional data through php script.
Suppose I have following items in JSON file.

```
[{"task":"get milk","done":false},
{"task":"get broccoli","done":false},
{"task":"bring rian","done":false},
{"task":"go to school","done":false}]
```

Now I want to add one more item from html page
    `{"task":"buy milk","done":false}`

And my html page looks like

```
Task:<input type="text" id="task" placeholder="what needs to be done?">
     <input type="button" value="ADD TASK" id="button">
```

How to do this through php in JQuery?

Comment: sure... Thanks Praveen for suggestion. I am new to this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first convert them into an array:

```
$array = json_decode('[{"task":"get milk","done":false},
    {"task":"get broccoli","done":false},
    {"task":"bring rian","done":false},
    {"task":"go to school","done":false}]', true);
```

Then append the new one to the array:

```
$array[] = array(
  "task" => $_REQUEST["task"],
  "done" => false
);
```

And then I'll convert it back to JSON.

```
$json = json_encode($array);
```

One issue is, when you are doing it, you are not passing the value of `task` correctly. You haven't specified a `name` attribute on the input:

```
<input type="text" name="task" id="task" placeholder="what needs to be done?" />
//-----------------^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Output: http://ideone.com/G6yj5P**

Answer (score 2):

Here we can first get all content using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Now decode that array using json_decode. Create one stdClass and create Anonymous Objects and assign values which are getting through AJAX request.

Following example can help you to create and add new object at the end of array. Simply file_put_contents can write into back to the file.

```
$array = json_decode('[{"task":"get milk","done":false},
    {"task":"get broccoli","done":false},
    {"task":"bring rian","done":false},
    {"task":"go to school","done":false}]', true);
$object = new stdClass();
$object->task = "milk";
$object->done = "false";
$array[] = $object;
$new_arr = json_encode($array);
```

You can refer AJAX request from this https://jsfiddle.net/wvuu9ax6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use submit form to get this, here is the code for post, you also can use get method.

php:

```
$tasks = json_decode(file_get_contents($taskFilePath), true);
$tasks[] =array("task" => $_POST["task"], "done" => $_post["done"]);
file_put_contents($taskFilePath, json_encode($tasks));
```